# KeyError is raised even though the key I call is part of the JSON dictionary

Tags: rapidapi

I'm experimenting with using the python request module along with RapidAPI. I carried out a POST request to Google Translate. It doesn't really matter what the details of the request were, but the response I received, in JSON format, was:

`{'data': {'detections': [[{'isReliable': False, 'confidence': 1, 'language': 'en'}]]}}`

I'm trying to print just the 'detections' part of the JSON dictionary, but python gives me a KeyError when I try to do this:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

result = response.json()

print(result['detections'])
```

Anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is a nested object, you can not access `detections` directly from the response. According to your scheme it should be like this;

```
print(result['data']['detections'])
```

Comment: Oh I completely forgot about that, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the key `detections` is nested within `data`. Try this instead:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
result = response.json()
print(result['data']['detections'])
```